# Android method getDomElement issue

Tags: android

I got some trouble with one line in my code..

```
public Document getDomElement(String task) {


 Document doc = null;
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try{

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource test = new InputSource();
        Log.i("TAG2","test01");
        test.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(task));
        Log.i("TAG2", "test02");

        doc = db.parse(test);

    } 

    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { 
     Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
     return null;
    } 
    catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
     return null;
    }

 return doc;
```

}

the first Logcat test01 is okay but not the second, so I think there is an error in this line

```
toto.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(task));
```

Comment: to parse use xmlpullparser it is recommended by google

Comment: But to Parse we have to get a document DOM before right ? :/ I don't understand

Comment: why do you need dom. to parse xml you can use xmlpullparser

Comment: upload the error log, please

Comment: the error log says that I have error on this line :
    toto.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(task));

and 

  Document doc = xml.getDomElement(task2);

I'm going to look at XMLPULLPARSER soon i think.. too bad because I spent time on DOM

Comment: change Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage()) to e.printStackTrace() then get the error log

Comment: sorry the Logcat is too big can't add to comment

Comment: @Raghunandan is XmlPullParser works with a xml on the web ? because all tutorial on the web have their own xml on local...

Comment: that is not an issue.